# How do you write multiple lists from Matlab to the same excel file?

Tags: excel, list, matlab

I have several lists in Matlab that I want to write to the same excel file.
I have one list `xordered` and another list `aspl`. I do not know the length of the lists till after I run the Matlab program.

I used

```
data = xlswrite('edgar.xls',fliplr(sortedx'),'A2:A3000')
```

for the first list but when I tried to write another list to the same file like this I ended up with two different excel files named edgar.xls

```
asp_data = xlswrite('edagr.xls', fliplr(aspl'), 'B2:B3000')
```

Is there a way I can write both of these lists into the same excel file? `xordered` in the A column and  `aspl` in the B column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d = [ fliplr(sortedaspl'), fliplr(sortedx')];

Makes a matrix from A2 to B300

data = xlswrite('edgar.xls',d,'A2:B300');